# Getting a download.mp3 or download.php file instead of TMH.mp3 file by download.php script

Tags: php, html

i have created a download.php file as

```
include('../../../phpsqlconnect.php');<br/>
$sel = mysqli_select_db($link, 'download');<br/>
$id=$_GET['id'];

if(is_numeric($id)){<br/>
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE id=$id');<br/>
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); <br/>
$url = $row['url']; // of course find the exact filename....<br/>
$name = $row['name'];        <br/>
header( 'Pragma: public' ); // required<br/>
header( 'Expires: 0' );<br/>
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );<br/>
header( 'Cache-Control: private', false ); // required for certain browsers<br/> 
header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );<br/>

header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($url) . '";' );<br/>
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );<br/>
header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $url ) );<br/>

readfile( $name );<br/>

exit;

}
```

this download.php is within a song folder & within song folder i have ppnh13 folder which  have ppnh.php fle
i have a download database & song table within it.
table song have 4 rows as id,url,name,movie...
in $row['url'], i have my file location as ppnh13\TMH.mp3
in $row['name'] , i have my file name as TMH

when i open the link `< href="../download.php?id=1">TMH</> from ppnh.php file<br/>`
i am getting a download.mp3 or download.php file instead of TMH.mp3 file

i want to make a common download.php file for all the folders within folder song.

Answer (score 1):

Use content type - application/exe instead of application/octet-stream &  it will work fine for all types of file download